# SFDX: Is it possible to retrieve and deploy Lead record type assignments for the Salutation standard value set?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, standard-field

I made some changes in the Salutation standard value set which I'd like to move across Sandboxes. For the picklist itself it's easy as the Salutation `StandardValueSet` is possible to retrieve via the `sfdx` command.

Problems start when I try to retrieve Record Type assignments for the Lead object for instance. The `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m RecordType:Lead.Lead` command does create the `Lead.recordType-meta.xml` file, however without the Salutation picklist assignment. I tried to add it manually with the following snippet:

```
<picklistValues>
    <picklist>Salutation</picklist>
    <values>
        <fullName>TestValue</fullName>
        <default>true</default>
    </values>
</picklistValues>
```

Sadly, with no success. The error which I received, when I tried to deploy it to another Sandbox:

> `force-app\main\default\objects\Lead\recordTypes\Lead.recordType-meta.xml  An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1240518550-106518 (111178417) (3:66)`

I'm a little surprised as other standard picklists are possible to manage this way, an Industry for instance - this one works pretty fine.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the Salutation picklist has other name in Record Type's XML configuration - it's "Name". Changing `<picklist>Salutation</picklist>` to `<picklist>Name</picklist>` in the snippet above fixes the problem. In overall, if one of Lead's record types is called "Lead", the `Lead.recordType-meta.xml` file should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RecordType xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Lead</fullName>
    <active>true</active>
    <businessProcess>Lead</businessProcess>
    <label>Lead</label>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>Industry</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>Oil&Gas</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Real Estate</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>Name</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>Mr.</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Ms.</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
</RecordType>
```